# Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'java.lang.String', required 'android.location.Location'

Tags: java, android, gps, sms

Hello I'm trying to send my location via SMS but keep getting this one error message which says:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'android.location.Location'
```

Inspection info:

```
sendLocationSMS(String,android.location.Location)
```

in FullscreenActivity cannot be applied to `(String,java.lang.String)`

Here's the specific lines of code that I'm using:

```
private void sendLocationSMS(String phoneNumber, Location currentLocation) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
    smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com?q=");
    smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLatitude());
    smsBody.append(",");
    smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLongitude());
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
}
```

In my onCreate I have this:

```
sendLocationSMS("MY PHONE NUMBER", "");
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? That method expectes an instance of Location. "" is an empty String, not an instance of location.

Comment: Please do not fundamentally change your question like that, especially after answers have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

In    `sendLocationSMS("MY PHONE NUMBER", "");`  second arg is a String, you should use a `Location` object. Try creating a new Location and put as second arg.

Comment: I did and it worked, but now in the new location a new error says: Cannot resolve constructor 'Location()'

Comment: How did you do it? You must `import android.location.Location;`. Then, you should be able to create a new Location instance by using `new Location("gps");`

Comment: I solved that problem by making a location class but a new problem exist. I edited the question up top.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty **String** as a second argument while your method requires you to pass a parameter that is of type `Location`. Thus change `sendLocationSMS("MY PHONE NUMBER", "");` to pass a variable of type `Location` in the second parameter. Try this on your onCreate
**I noticed you didn't read about the ``Location``` class, so read it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location)**

```
String provider = ""; // change this to your provider
Location currentLocation = new Location(provider);
sendLocationSMS("MY PHONE NUMBER", currentLocation);
```

Comment: It got rid of that error but now a new error says: Cannot resolve constructor 'Location()'

Comment: Is the ```Location``` class your own implementation? or is it a class implemented by Java? If it is a  class implemented by Java kindly attach the link for the doc. Or just go directly to the   ```Location``` class and see how it can be initialized

Comment: It's my own class I added to my splash screen. Any way I can initialize it?

Comment: Can you post your ```Location``` class? And I will try to update my answer based on your ```Location``` class

Comment: I didn't make a separate location class. I just added the dependency's and thought the code would work with just that. How do I make a location class?

Comment: You said you made your own ```Location``` class. I have edited my answer

Comment: Ok I made a location class using FusedLocationProviderClient but the results of the GPS coordinates keep reading 0.0,0.0. I edited the question above to reflect the new code including the location class.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers say, this is clear argument type mismatch. 
Find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java) how to get the current location. If you do not want to pass the actual location data, just create a new Location object and pass it to the method call.

Comment: I tried everything on that page but it is still returning 0.0,0.0

Comment: Did you add the permission to manifest? And give permission in the app?

Comment: Yes I added coarse access and fine access permissions and my phone has location permission for the app.